# Как получить у класса-шаблона доступ к вложенному классу?

Tags: c#, generics

Я хочу в CalculatePrice<T> передавать тип Bus или Tractor так, чтобы в T получать доступ к внутреннему классу Tire.

```
public class Auto
{
    public class Tire { }
}

public class Tractor : Auto { }

public class Bus : Auto { }

public class CalculatePrice<T> where T : Auto
{
    public CalculatePrice(ref T item)
    {
        Tractor.Tire ex0;
        Bus.Tire ex1;
        T.Tire ex2; // why error?
    }
}
```

Comment: Вместо картинки вставьте код. И покажите классы-наследники.

Comment: Почитайте [Рекомендации по проектированию](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/ms229042(v=vs.110).aspx). В частности, Правила именования.

Comment: Используйте просто `auto.tire`, наследование от `auto` не порождает новых классов `tire`, класс `tire` всего один. Вы можете убедиться в этом, написав `tractor.tire a = new bus.tire();` и это удачно скомпилируется, более того, VS2017 предлагает обе записи "упростить" до вида `auto.tire`

Comment: Тогда вопрос закрыт, действительно ступил. Спасибо!